Azure web app : can't configure a value for "site_config.0.linux_fx_version"
I try deploy an Azure web app for containers. My terraform code looks like this:
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "example" {

      name                = "test123-webapp"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example.id
    
      site_config {
        linux_fx_version                        = "DOCKER|mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/staticsite:latest"
        container_registry_use_managed_identity = true
        always_on                               = true
      }
    
      app_settings = {
        "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL"      = "https://${azurerm_container_registry.example.login_server}"
        "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME" = azurerm_container_registry.example.admin_username
        "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD" = azurerm_container_registry.example.admin_password
      }
    }

With this code, I get an error:
│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│ 
│   with azurerm_linux_web_app.example,
│   on webapp.tf line 35, in resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "example":
│   35:     linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/staticsite:latest"
│
│ Can't configure a value for "site_config.0.linux_fx_version": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.

I couldn't find much documentation on terraform code. When I do manually on the portal, I see the configuration as below:
"siteProperties": {
    "metadata": null,
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "LinuxFxVersion",
            "value": "DOCKER|mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/staticsite:latest"
        },
        {
            "name": "WindowsFxVersion",
            "value": null
        }
    ],

I have tried removing 'DOCKER|' prefix but same error.
My tf version is Terraform v1.9.3 and azurerm is v3.112.0.
Any idea why I get this error on my terraform code?

Have you tried with the azurerm_app_service provider. @MoonHorse

no, as you have said in your answer, as my azurerm version is 3.112, I am using linux web app.

You need to use an azurerm_app_service resource to deploy a web app for containers if you are using 3.11 and earlier versions.
After upgraded it to the latest version releases, azurerm_app_service is further converted as azurerm_linux_web_app for Linux Os type.
In order to deploy a web app for containers with azurerm 3.11 version releases, use azurerm_app_service as shown below.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.111.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
subscription_id = "xxxx"
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "xxx"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "examplejah"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "example" {
  name                = "ahRegistry1j"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Premium"
  admin_enabled       = true
}
resource "azurerm_app_service" "backend" {
  name                = "jahservice12new"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.example.id
  app_settings = {
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL          = azurerm_container_registry.example.login_server
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME     = azurerm_container_registry.example.admin_username
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD     = azurerm_container_registry.example.admin_password
  }

  site_config {
    always_on = "true"
    # define the images to used for you application
    linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|${azurerm_container_registry.example.login_server}"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

Refer blog for the similar deployment for dockerised web app.
Deployment succeeded:



If you want to deploy a container app with latest version (4.0) releases, you can use azurerm_container_app provider as given.

As I have said in my question, I am using azurerm version 3.112 so I need to use azurerm_linux_web_app.

Have you checked the above solution. @MoonHorse

I needed to use azurerm_linux_web_app, your solution has azurerm_app_service. But I have found a solution. I will write that. thanks anyway for your help, I appreciate it.

@MoonHorse can you share your solution please if you found one?
